Package siunitx, xcookybooky Error: Package 'units' incompatible with Overleaf, LaTeX 2024, and pdflatex
I’m trying to compile a LaTeX document in Overleaf using the siunitx and xcookybooky packages. However, when I load both packages, I receive the following error:

Package siunitx Error: Package 'units' incompatible. For immediate
help type H . l.13 \begin{document}

I am using Overleaf, LaTeX 2024, and compiling with pdflatex. This issue occurs specifically when I load the xcookybooky package, which internally loads the units package that conflicts with siunitx.
Steps to Reproduce:
Here’s the minimal example that reproduces the error:
\documentclass{article}

% Load siunitx for units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale = FR,        % Use commas for decimal separators
  detect-all          % Adjust fonts automatically
}

% Load xcookybooky (will work as is on Overleaf)
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\begin{document}

% Example usage of siunitx
Here is a test of siunitx: \SI{10.5}{\kilogram}.

% Example recipe with xcookybooky
\begin{recipe}
  [preparationtime = {\SI{30}{\minute}},
   bakingtime = {\SI{45}{\minute}},
   bakingtemperature = {\SI{180}{\celsius}},
   portion = 4 portions]
  {Example Recipe}

  \ingredients{
    \SI{200}{\gram} flour \\
    \SI{100}{\gram} sugar \\
    \SI{50}{\milli\liter} milk
  }

  \preparation{
    \step Mix the ingredients together.
    \step Bake in the oven at \SI{180}{\celsius} for \SI{45}{\minute}.
  }
\end{recipe}

\end{document}


Error Message: typescript Copy code Package siunitx Error: Package
'units' incompatible. For immediate help type H . l.13
\begin{document}

This error occurs when the siunitx package is loaded first, followed by the xcookybooky package. The issue seems to stem from xcookybooky loading the units package, which is incompatible with siunitx.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the document to compile without errors, displaying the recipe and unit measurements as expected, using both siunitx for units and xcookybooky for recipe formatting.
What I Have Tried:
I’ve tried changing the load order of the packages.
I’ve attempted using \PassOptionsToPackage to prevent xcookybooky from loading the units package, but that hasn’t resolved the issue.
Question:
Has anyone encountered this issue with siunitx and xcookybooky in Overleaf? Is there a known solution or workaround to avoid this conflict without modifying the core xcookybooky package?
Thank you in advance for any assistance!
Edit:
siunitx only seems to throw the error as a side-effect.  I see no other problems?  Maybe it should be a warning?

the simpler thing to do would be to follow xcookybooky and its use of the older units package, if it's not written to work with siunitx, there is no reason to expect every package to be compatible with every other one

this really doesn't have anything to do with overleaf. your editor is not to blame for package conflicts ;).

Unrelated to the problem with siunitx, I'd suggest to use the xcookybooky version from github instead of the one from overleaf. A couple of errors have been fixed in the github version: https://github.com/SvenHarder/xcookybooky (I think overleaf/texlive has a 2015 version)

I get an error even without siunitx (using the texlive version), despite defining all the unit commands.

@cfr my MVE only needs \SI{}{} redifined as far as I know.

@DavidCarlisle Your point is well-taken, but for the pedantic among us, the rich use of units in recipes makes them a prime candidate for ensuring compatibility.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  How can we lobby for the inclusion of the updated version in texlive? This will then migrate to Overleaf.

but do you really need more than the units package recipies use units but usually fairly simple quantities, not likely to need gigametres per second squared, otherwise you'd need to make a modified recipe class using siunitx

"How can we lobby for the inclusion of the updated version in texlive?" no lobbying is necessary, you just need to get a new version on ctan, either just make one with a new name and submit to ctan, or if you want an update with the same name, you (usually) need to contact the original author

@skvery Convince the author of xcookybooky to upload a new version to ctan and it will automatically be included in texlive and, a year later or so, in overleaf.

@DavidCarlisle You don't measure your crispy duck in electron volt?

Seems the issue is with siunitx being too sensitive about the inclusion of units.  Maybe it will be fixed?

@skvery This is a deliberate decision from siunitx, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/690609/36296

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz May I suggest that a warning is more appropriate as it does not really break anything.

@skvery in v3, siunitx defines the command \unit, which would clash with units. As siunitx was first released in 2008, the idea that by now people will have migrated from older units packages is I hope not unreasonable!

You can prevent xcookybooky to load the units package with
\expandafter\def\csname ver@unit.\@pkgextension\endcsname{}

(or, since 2023, \disable@package@load}{unit}{}).
In the xcookybooky package, I found only one use of the \unit command, from the unit package: in the \portion command. Redefine it to make it compatible with siunitx
\renewcommand*{\portion}[2][\xcb@name@portionvalue]
{%
  \unit{#2}{#1}
}

But this don't remove the error message from siunitx. So add
\expandafter\let\csname ver@units.\@pkgextension\endcsname\relax

The units package will then not be considered loaded.
Example (fixing the missing & in \ingredients and with an enumerate environment inside the \preparation command, as \step gives me an error):
\documentclass{article}

% Load siunitx for units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  locale = FR,        % Use commas for decimal separators
  detect-all          % Adjust fonts automatically
}

% Prevent xcookybooky to load the unit package
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname ver@unit.\@pkgextension\endcsname{}
\makeatother

% Load xcookybooky (will work as is on Overleaf)
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\portion}[2][\xcb@name@portionvalue]
{%
  \unit{#2}{#1}
}
\makeatother

% Remove units from the list of loaded packages
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname ver@units.\@pkgextension\endcsname\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Example usage of siunitx
Here is a test of siunitx: \SI{10.5}{\kilogram}.

% Example recipe with xcookybooky
\begin{recipe}
  [preparationtime = {\SI{30}{\minute}},
    bakingtime = {\SI{45}{\minute}},
    bakingtemperature = {\SI{180}{\celsius}},
    portion = 4 portions]
  {Example Recipe}

  \ingredients{
    \SI{200}{\gram} & flour \\
    \SI{100}{\gram} & sugar \\
    \SI{50}{\milli\liter} & milk
  }

  \preparation{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Mix the ingredients together.
    \item Bake in the oven at \SI{180}{\celsius} for \SI{45}{\minute}.
    \end{enumerate}
  }
\end{recipe}

\end{document}



% Remove units from the list of loaded packages
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname ver@units.\@pkgextension\endcsname\relax
\makeatother
worked for me!

@skvery Yes, it masks the units package for siunitx. But it would be better not to load the units package at all.

for me it does not break anything, in fact I can use both:  \unit[]{} and \SI{}{}.
